# Torus shaped solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I need to use one of those for an experiment (a solenoid with the shape of a torus). Unfortunately, as you can see, I don't know the appropriate name for it. I have built myself a temporary one but I'd much rather buy an industrial-made one to be certain about it's efficiency, and for that I need the name. Here is a picture of one that I made:

[image]

Comment: Unpload the photo somewhere publically accessible and post a link here as a comment and someone can edit to include in your question.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/100405825@N05/9534678061/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solenoid is a type of actuator; what your picture shows is a [**toroidal inductor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_inductors_and_transformers). And don't worry *too* much about getting a premade one; unless you have high-volume or high-precision needs, self-wound ones are fine if you know the specs of the toroid.